# Getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, nullreferenceexception

I have two aspx pages webfrom1.aspx and webform2.aspx. In webform1 i have two textboxes and i want to send the textbox data(enterend by the user)to the webform2. I have used query string method.
I'm getting exception on 
**string text = ((TextBox)lastOne.FindControl("MAIL")).Text;**
I'm getting System.NullReferenceException on the code.
Here is the webform2 code.

````
        {
            string name = Request.QueryString["Name"];

            if (name == "MAIN")
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    string fname = "Anonymous";
                    string lname = "Anonymous";
                    string email = "";
                    string mesg = "";

                    Page lastOne = (Page)Context.Handler;
                    string text = ((TextBox)lastOne.FindControl("MAIL")).Text;
                    LabelEMAIL.Text = text;
                    LabelMESG.Text = ((TextBox)lastOne.FindControl("MESAGE")).Text;
                    LabelFNAME.Text = fname;
                    LabelLNAME.Text = lname;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
                }
            }
        } ```
*webfrom1 has the following code*
``` <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>Email: </td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox ID="MAIL" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" TextMode="Email" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                   <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" BackColor="White" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="MAIL"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Message: </td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox ID="MESAGE" runat="server" Height="139px" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" Width="223px" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
                   <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="MESAGE"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
               </tr>
           </table>

               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" PostBackUrl="~/ResponseBack.aspx" Text="Submit" /> ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Look  all the proeprties in   "lastOne " variable by quick watch, you can find what is available into this,If  "Mail" Text box is there,kindly look at its "id" property.